# Can emacs be used across multiple screens?

Tags: linux, ssh, multiple-monitors, emacs, r

I would like to use emacs across multiple monitors: one monitor would have code the other would have the R session that will be processing the code submissions. I am in a Windows machine logging into a server via SSH. I am using emacs with an Xwindow (the lag is just too much with X on - therefore I run `emacs -nw`).  Is this possible?

*EDIT: When I ssh into my cluster, two terminal sessions may physically be connected to two different nodes on the cluster (two different login nodes)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your situation, I would think a good way to do it would be to use emacs in server mode, and have two X terminals (one in each screen), each running a frame attached to the same server.

1. open the first terminal, ssh to the host as usual and run: `emacs -nw`
2. start the server in yout emacs instance: <kbd>M-x</kbd>`server-start`<kbd>RET</kbd>
3. open a second terminal, ssh to the host and run: `emacsclient -nw`

You now have two distinct emacs frames sharing the same buffers, which allows you to do pretty much everything you want.

Comment: i get teh following error:
`emacsclient: can't find socket; have you started the server?
To start the server in Emacs, type "M-x server-start".
emacsclient: No socket or alternate editor.  Please use:

        --socket-name
        --server-file      (or environment variable EMACS_SERVER_FILE)
        --alternate-editor (or environment variable ALTERNATE_EDITOR)`

Comment: This problem is likely related to the information you added in the EDIT to your question: if emacsclient does not run on the same system/node, it will not find the server. After opening the second ssh connection to the cluster, try doing one more ssh connection to the same node as your emacs server.